# How to Cast String Array To Ilist

Tags: c#

I have this class :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id;
    public ICollection<Role> Roles;
}
```

And I have this object :

```
User userObj = new User { Id = 1 };
```

I want set this array :

```
RolesVM.Items.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

For :

```
userObj.Roles
```

When assign the `string[]` array to the `Roles`, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

How  can I do this ?

Comment: You're asking how to assign a value to a field?  You're already doing it right in the code that you've already shown.  You've done it before, why is the 3rd time any harder?

Comment: when I assign string array to Icollection property , igetting error

Comment: Yes, because a string array isn't a collection of roles.  That should make sense.  Either create a collection of roles, or change the class to contain a collection of strings.

Comment: What does the Role class look like?  It would be easier to advise if we knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magical way to transform `string` to other type. You need to call code that creates objects of that type somehow.

I.e. if `role` have constructor taking a string argument:

```
userObj.Roles = 
    RolesVM.Items.Split(new string[] {"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
      .Select(value => new role(value))  // "convert" strings to `role` 
      .ToList(); // transform enumerable to type that implements ICollection (List)
```

Depending on your `role` type `new role(value)` may need to be replaced with other conversion like `new role{ Value = value}` or for enums - `Enum.Parse(typeof(role), value)`.